# Entity Framework Missing Partial

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am learning the Entity Framework and I decided to create a simple console application that uses Entity framework with two tables.

I've created two tables: http://wstaw.org/w/LrL/

I have appropiate classes for the database.

This is the code.

The Contact class.

```
public class Contact
{
     public int ContactID { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

And the Address class.

```
public class Address
{
     public int AddressID { get; set; }
     public string Street { get; set; }
     public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Visual studio shows Following Errors.

> Error 3 Missing partial modifier on declaration of 
>   type 'MyEntityPOCO.Contact'; another partial 
>   declaration of this type exists Contact.c  8 19 MyEntityPOCO
>
> Error  4   Missing partial modifier on declaration of type
>   'MyEntityPOCO.Address'; another partial declaration of this type
>    exists Address.cs 8 19 MyEntityPOCO
>
> Error  1   Running transformation: Please overwrite the
>   replacement token '$edmxInputFile$' with the actual name of the 
>   .edmx file you would like to generate from. MyEntityPOCO\Model1.tt 1 1

How might I resolve these errors?

Comment: Are you doing a code-first entity framework implementation ? If not you will generate these classes from the database into a entity model using the entity mapping tool.

Comment: First i Created a Code , next I create appropiate classes next add  Ado.net   Entity Data model and i generate model from database.

Comment: BUt when I deleted Contact class and Address class the solution is compiling.
But I dont know why I can not cleate appropiate classes for the base,

Comment: It is OK now.

I ought to select my .edmx file and click properties and select Code Generation strategy to None.

Problem is solved.

Answer (score 4):

The partial keyword is used to declare a class in more than one code file. It is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

What has happened in your case is that you have a class decorated with the partial keyword (the one created in the *yourmodel*.edmx.cs file by EF), and another class with the same name in the same namespace.

Normally with two classes with the same name in the same namespace (without the partial keyword) you would get a class name conflict exception. In this case, because one of the two classes is marked as partial, the C# compiler generates the error that you are seeing.

Suggested solution: Search your code for the other class, determine how it got there and either rename it, move it to a different namespace or also mark it with partial if it is meant to be the same class.

Comment: While the other answers are right too, I think this answer is better than the others since it explains WHY the classes are required to be partial.

Comment: I changed the class name so why am I still getting this error?

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu - Delete all your DLL files from /bin and /obj - you could have stale assemblies lying around. If that doesn't work, search your code with a text search tool for the offending class name. If you are getting the "another partial declaration" error, you will definitely find more than one occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Database First Entity Framework, so you created the database and did drag-and-drop to move the entities into an edmx.

It also looks like you might have manually created classes for Contact and Address. Is this the case? You don't need to do this because Entity Framework will generate the classes for you.

Comment: But I dont have any classes now and the solution is compiling.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an Entity in Entity Framework, EF will automatically create the classes for you and label them as PARTIAL classes.  Therefore, you can use them immediately 'out of the box'.

This is why it's saying you need to create them as partial classes... it already has a class named 'Address' that's labeled as partial, so it thinks this new one should be the other 'part' of that class, but you simply forgot to label it that way.

If you wanted to extend what that class can do, and add functions inside that class, you could do something like:

```
public partial class Address {...}
```

but it looks like you may simply be trying to re-define the class again.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem visual studio was generating **.edmx** file but was not generating classes. After spending half day, I got the solution.

**Use different Version of MVC framework while creating project:**
Try to use .net MVC 4.5 version or any other version while creating project.

**Use different version of entity framework**
When I was adding entity framework data model, I changed entity framework version from 6.x to 5.0.

THat's it.